# how to delete selected item in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I create a listview called listBoxobj. I want to delete the listview based on the selected listview but right now the problem is that when deleting it will delete by index not the selected item.

This is for an apps develops in visual studio,running SQLite.

i've already tried to use this code but keep failed

```
foreach ( ListViewItem eachItem in listBoxobj.SelectedItems)
{
    listBoxobj.Items.Remove(eachItem);
}
```

I want the selected listview will be deleted instead the listview deleted by index

```
private void DeleteMV_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DatabaseHelperMV_Meriam delete = new DatabaseHelperMV_Meriam();
    x = listBoxobj.SelectedItems;//this line keep getting error
    delete.DeleteId(x);
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(MV_MeriamViewData));
}
```

Comment: x has to be an object or a var

Comment: x is a var that i declared

Comment: The main question here is: Is this winforms or wpf?

Comment: @Mikev it is wpf

Answer (score 2):

**For WinForms:**

You delete list view selected item using this:

```
listBoxobj.SelectedItems[0].Remove();
```

This code you have:

```
foreach ( ListViewItem eachItem in listBoxobj.SelectedItems)
{
   listBoxobj.Items.Remove(eachItem);
}
```

Is corrected if you have `multiselect = true`... but if you have `multiselect = false`, use this: `listBoxobj.SelectedItems[0].Remove();`

**For WPF:**

```
private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{     
    var selected = listBoxobj.SelectedItems.Cast<Object>().ToArray();
    foreach (var item in selected)
    {
        listBoxobj.Items.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: i've already tried this but still keep getting error. Its said that object does not contain a definition  for 'Remove'

Comment: @imran try the Edit2